# Could you form quartz crystals by melting and cooling sand very slowly?

Tags: synthesis, crystal-structure, recrystallization

Since glass is amorphous quartz and when you slow the cooling of something enough it will crystallize, couldn’t you melt $\ce{SiO2}$ (sand) and then very slowly cool it to cause spontaneous nucleation and form quartz crystals?

If so, then why hasn’t it been used before? It would seem to be a better method than flux because in flux you need many chemicals and a dissolving chemical or mix and it is a complicated and very long process to grow very small crystals throughout the whole mix. If you simply cooled a molten mixture slowly enough to cause complete crystallization, then the entire mix of molten crystal would need to form crystal because it all is cooling down.

Comment: About the second part of your question, both the α- and the β-phase of quartz have what we call an enantiomorphic space group. It forms spirals that can be 'enantiomers' to each other, which I guess also gives it its properties. For many applications you often need the pure enantiomer which will grow in a seed of the correct orientation under for example hydrothermal conditions.

Comment: Melting and cooling will give you a bunch of crystals lumped together. Why would you want that? Then again, I've seen single crystals of quartz as big as a tabletop, and they were **not** made by melting.

Comment: see eg https://www.ndk.com/catalog/AN-SQC_GG_e.pdf

Comment: In principle, maybe. But that isn't how big crystals are formed in nature. Most deposit from solutions not from melted pure silica.

Comment: @NightWriter Your example post is about hydrothermal growth of a crystal.

Comment: @Buttonwood Sure, but it includes a partial explanation of *why* that process is employed, which is at the root of the question